# How to identify time, lon, and lat coordinates in xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

What is the best way to determine which coordinates of an `xarray` `dataArray` object contain `longitude`, `latitude` and `time`?

A typical `dataArray` might look like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (ensemble: 9, lat: 224, lon: 464, time: 12054)
Coordinates:
  * lat        (lat) float64 25.06 25.19 25.31 25.44 ... 52.56 52.69 52.81 52.94
  * lon        (lon) float64 -124.9 -124.8 -124.7 ... -67.31 -67.19 -67.06
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-01 1980-01-02 ... 2012-12-31
Dimensions without coordinates: ensemble
Data variables:
    elevation  (lat, lon) float64 dask.array<shape=(224, 464), chunksize=(224, 464)>
    temp       (ensemble, time, lat, lon) float64 dask.array<shape=(9, 12054, 224, 464), chunksize=(1, 287, 224, 464)>
```

One approach could be to loop through the variables identified by the variable coords, like `temp.coords`, looking for the `standard_name` attributes of `time`, `longitude`, and `latitude`.  But many datasets don't seem to include `standard_name` attributes for all variables.

I guess another approach be to search over the `units` attributes and try to identify if they have appropriate `units` attributes (e.g. `degrees_east` or `degrees_west` for `longitude`, etc).

Is there a better way?

Comment: I just loop and look for `latitude`/`lat` and `longitude`/`lon`. Is there a convention outlined somewhere? `time`/`date`/`day`/etc. are also tough. some common climate data library with `climate_toolz.standardize_dims` would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MetPy package](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy) includes some helpers for systematic coordinate identification like this. You can see the basics of how this works in the [xarray with MetPy tutorial](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/dev/tutorials/xarray_tutorial.html#coordinates). For example, if you want the time coordinate of a DataArray called `temp` (assuming it came from a dataset that has been parsed by MetPy), you would simply call:

```
temp.metpy.time
```

This is done internally by parsing the coordinate metadata according to the [CF conventions](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html#coordinate-types).

Here's a short example:

```
import xarray as xr
import metpy.calc as mpcalc

ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')
ds = ds.metpy.parse_cf()

x,y,t = ds['air'].metpy.coordinates('x','y','time')

print([coord.name for coord in (x, y, t)])
```

which produces:

```
['lon', 'lat', 'time']
```

Comment: When I first tried installing `metpy` into my conda environment, it wanted to upgrade and downgrade a bunch of stuff.  For this coordinate identification it was sufficient to use `conda install -c conda-forge metpy pint pooch --no-deps`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something similar to the code below with xarray filter_by:

```
def x_axis(nc):
    xnames = ['longitude', 'grid_longitude', 'projection_x_coordinate']
    xunits = [
        'degrees_east',
        'degree_east',
        'degree_E',
        'degrees_E',
        'degreeE',
        'degreesE',
    ]
    xvars = list(set(
        nc.get_variables_by_attributes(
            axis=lambda x: x and str(x).lower() == 'x'
        ) +
        nc.get_variables_by_attributes(
            standard_name=lambda x: x and str(x).lower() in xnames
        ) +
        nc.get_variables_by_attributes(
            units=lambda x: x and str(x).lower() in xunits
        )
    ))
    return xvars
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for just the special coords that act as indexes, then you can iterate over the `ds.indexes` and do some string parsing on their names. Something like:

```
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')
ds.lat.attrs.pop('standard_name')

for k in ds.indexes.keys():
    v = ds[k]
    sn = v.attrs.get('standard_name')
    if not sn:
        if 'lon' in k:
            v.attrs.update(standard_name='longitude')
            continue
        if 'lat' in k:
            v.attrs.update(standard_name='latitude')
            continue
        if 'time' in k or k in ['day', 't', 'month', 'year']:
            v.attrs.update(standard_name='time')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we should lean heavily on CF conventions. They exist precisely for this reason. So I would recommend separating this problem into two parts:

- Fixing non-CF-complaint datasets (perhaps a small library for this purpose would make sense--it could contain the logic to translate common variable names into appropriate `standard_name` attributes)
- Parsing CF-complaint datasets (can leverage `standard_name` attributes)

Comment: I like this idea.  Could  `standard_name` also be provided by an [Intake Catalog](https://intake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)?